# SQLite error (10) and error(14)

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I have this code:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connstr))
using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(commandText, conn))
using (SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd))
{     
    da.Fill(ds);
}
return ds;
```

On DataAdapter Fill i see and exception on Visual Studio debug window:

```
SQLite error (10): delayed 1375ms for lock/sharing conflict
SQLite error (14): os_win.c:36702: (5) winOpen(C:\Users\blahblah\MyDb.db) - Access denied.
```

I'm using SQLite for .NET Framework 4 'Client Profile' version 1.0.94

Comment: The application is sinlge-user, not multiple access to database. For testing pourposes i just executed that code spnippet 1st off all my logic. Im not writting anything, just selecting (select blah, blah, blah from blahblah)

Comment: *Something* has the file open, which may be your process from a previous run. The error message is caused specifically by a **sharing conflict**, which indicates the file is opened already. We can't investigate that for you from where we're sitting.

Comment: @KenWhite i just noticed that my SQLite database file has "read only" attribute (maybe caused by some kind of 'protection' from TFS). Just removing the "read only" attribute and works like a charm again.